# How would you react if a reference book you're reading contains religious undertones?

Tags: religious-issues

One reference book I'm reading contains religious undertones in favor of Christianity. In one chapter, for example, the author quoted a biblical verse in support of her claim that the 21st century is the "Asian Century".

Comment: What is the question you want to answered?

Comment: What do you mean by "in support of"?  I find it hard to believe the book says something like "as predicted in biblical prophecy, the 21st century will be the Asian century."  By contrast, some bible verses have become proverbs in English (for example, a leopard changing his spots, or a house divided against itself) and no longer carry any significant religious baggage.  And of course there's a whole continuum between these extremes.

Answer (score 2):

The same as you do (hopefully) with every other reference: be **critical** about it and only take it as serious as you think you can.

Or:
What would you do if the book writes "When I threw a coin, it was head, therefore the 21th century seems to be..." ?

Take the parts and conclusions which seem reasonable but, as always, be aware of bullshit.

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on the institution at which you are studying, and the topic you are studying. If you are studying Engineering at MIT, then I would have severe reservations at the content of the book, and the use of the references. If, however, you are studying theology at Oral Roberts, then there is a clear need to review the book it light of the subject matter.

Comment: The subject is History and the institution claims to be non-sectarian.

Comment: In that situation, and the book is a required reading, then I would read the book cover to cover. In any assignment based on the book, I would include a caveat, or critical observation, on the religious overtones. I would also report the book to your institutions standards and ethics committee, highlighting the issues, and concerns that you have regarding the text. Include quotations in context.